# java apache poi date format and blank cell handling

Tags: java, apache-poi, date-format

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook07 = new XSSFWorkbook(xlname);                     
XSSFSheet sheet1 = workbook07.getSheet(sheetname);
CellReference cvalue = new CellReference("E11"); 
Row nrow = sheet1.getRow(cvalue.getRow());
Cell cell = (nrow.getCell(cvalue.getCol());
```

when am trying to get a date value of `1/9/2009` from a cell means, its returning it in some format like `1-oct-2009`. i need to get the exact format of the date what ever in the cell, and print it as a output ..that means i need out put as `1/9/2009`.

and i have to ask one more, using this if am trying to get a blankcell values its returning null.pointer exception ..
its returning exception while getting the values itself so i cont able to handle it

```
Cell cell = (nrow.getCell(cvalue.getCol());
```

so i can't able handle it like this

```
if {cell.Cell_TYPE_}
```

can any one plz help me out..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the cell is really a Date cell (and not a String cell where someone has typed in a date by hand as a String), just call [Cell.getDateCellValue()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getDateCellValue%28%29) and you'll get back a Java Date object

You can also use [DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html#isCellDateFormatted%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell%29) if you want to check if a cell is a date one or not (Excel doesn't have a specific type for date cells, they're just number cells with special formatting rules)